# Running function chain order, order.price

Tags: r, quantstrat

Goal: produce a stop limit using time stamp (aka not a trailing stop). Most of the coding is stolen from Ilya Kipnis' design for calculating position size based on ATR. The link to the code is in comments, below, so it could be reproduced.

I'm fairly certain that the function produces the desired effect, but I don't know what type of information the order.price requires. It seems I need to indicate that this is a function, not a number.

I'm running the following function in a chain order, to calculate order.price.

```
stopATR <- function(atrMod="") {
  atrString <- paste0("atr",atrMod)
  atrCol <- grep(atrString, colnames(mktdata))
  atrTimeStamp <- mktdata[timestamp, atrCol]
  atrStop <- atrTimeStamp * pctATR*100
  atrString <- paste0("EMA.currentPrice")
  priceCol <- grep(atrString, colnames(mktdata))
  currentPrice <- mktdata[timestamp, priceCol]
  out <- currentPrice-atrStop
  colnames(out) <- "atrStopLoss"
  return(out)
}

#rules
add.rule(strategy.st, name="ruleSignal", 
         arguments=list(sigcol="buyTrigger", sigval=TRUE, ordertype="market", 
                        orderside="long", replace=FALSE, prefer="Open", 
                        osFUN=osDollarATR, tradeSize=tradeSize,
                        pctATR=pctATR, atrMod="X"), 
         type="enter", path.dep=TRUE,
         label="newEntry")

add.rule(strategy.st, name="ruleSignal", 
         arguments=list(sigcol="buyTrigger", sigval=TRUE, ordertype="stoplimit", 
                        orderside="long", replace=FALSE, 
                        orderqty='all',
                        order.price=stopATR,
                        orderset="orders"), 
         type="chain",
         parent="newEntry",
         label="stopLossLong",
         path.dep=TRUE)
```

The error is:

```
Error in as.numeric(orderprice) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

Comment: http://eliassimpson.com/investing/wp-content/uploads/system_3.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following function and run it through add.indicator. Then I just refer to the column in mktdata to use it as a stoplimit.

```
stopOut <- function (x, n, maType, HLC, pctATR) {
  EMA <- EMA(x, n, maType=maType)
  ATR <- ATR(HLC, n=n, maType=maType)
  ATR <- ATR$atr
  atrStop <- EMA - (ATR*100*pctATR)
  return(atrStop)
}

add.indicator(strategy.st, name="stopOut",
              arguments=list(x=quote(HLC(mktdata)), n=period, wilder=TRUE, HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata)), pctATR=pctATR),
              label="stopLimit")

add.rule(strategy.st, name="ruleSignal", 
         arguments=list(sigcol="buyTrigger", 
                        sigval=TRUE, 
                        ordertype="stoplimit", 
                        orderside="long", 
                        replace=FALSE, 
                        orderqty='all',
                        order.price=quote(mktdata$EMA.stopLimit[timestamp]),
                        orderset="orders"),
         type="chain",
         parent="newEntry",
         label="takeProfitLong",
         path.dep=TRUE)
```